# Allow certain exit codes to not abort execution in bash "-e" mode

Tags: command-line, bash, umount

If `umount` returns 0 as the exit code, this script continues.
Some times, the exit code is 127, I'm okay with it and the script
should continue. How can I modify the script to do such a "whitelisting"
of allowed umount exit codes?

```
set -e
sudo umount /drive || [ $? -eq 0 ] 
echo do stuff
```

If such a technique exists, I have many use cases for it.

Comment: `sudo umount /drive || true` to force a successful exit status

Comment: The only exit codes I want to "allow" are zero and 127

Answer (score 2):

Let's try this:

```
if sudo mount /drive; then
    : # exit status 0
else
    rc=$?
    [ $rc -ne 127 ] && exit $rc
fi
```

Test with this -- experiment with different values for `status`

```
env status=0 bash -e -c '
    mycmd() { return $1; }
    if mycmd $status; then
        :
    else
        rc=$?
        [ $rc -ne 127 ] && exit $rc
    fi
    echo OK
'
```

Comment: is there a more concise one liner perhaps...

Comment: Untested `mycmd || [ $? -eq 127 ] || exit`

Comment: OP tested it, so you can add the comment to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a case statement to whitelist or take another action.

```
sudo umount /drive

case $? in
        0)
                ;;
        127)
                ;;
        *)
                echo 'bailing!'
                exit 1
                ;;
esac

echo 'doing more stuff'
```

Comment: is there a more concise one liner perhaps...

Answer (score -1):

This [answer-in-a-comment by glenn jackman](/questions/996677/allow-certain-exit-codes-to-not-abort-execution-in-bash-e-mode#comment1610222_996750) works for me:

```
mycmd || [ $? -eq 127 ] || exit
```

Comment: Please don't post "Thank you" or something similar as answer. Remove this post and instead mark the [according answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/996750/423684) as the accepted one.

Comment: but it's a comment, the answer was given as a comment

Comment: @derHugo: I think in this case it's acceptable since there is no *answer* post to which this refers, only a comment. I'd rather have it captured in a proper answer and go through the usual system of votes and checks and criticism than the original unchecked comment.

Comment: @David Foerster I would rather ask the user who posted the answer to which the comment was added, to edit his answer and add the one-liner solution to his answer since it was actually "his idea"

Comment: @derHugo: If that happens I will happily flag this answer as a duplicate. At the moment I'd prefer it to stay than to go.